# how to find the user profile property scope which user has set on his mysite - SharePoint 2010?

Tags: development, powershell

How can I find the list of colleagues/Team-members for a SharePoint 2010 user? and how can i find the scope for a specific user profile property (eg..birthday--->Everyone, Interest--->My Team)which user has set on his Mysite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UserProfile class has a [Colleagues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofile.colleagues.aspx) property that contains a [ColleagueManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.colleaguemanager.aspx).

MSDN has some examples on how to work with the new User Profile classes and UserProfileManager [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager.aspx).

Comment: $UserCM = $usrprofile.Colleagues;
($UserCM.GetItems() | where {$_.Group -eq "Peers" } )
$usrprofile["HomePhone"].Privacy